# Magento Dropship Extension

Tags: extensions

I have added a dropship extension to my Magento and it is asking for the following. "Attribute code for your vendor attribute. Must be a dropdown attribute." Please help... is this a particular code?

Comment: Since we don't know which module or how it works it's impossible to answer this question

Comment: @SanderMangel I disagree. The question boils down to "what is an attribute code"

Comment: @fschmengler hm, good point. If that's enough for OP I guess the module is not required

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much @fschmengler. Sorry everyone if this was off topic. I am new here so learning the ropes and where best to ask the right questions! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the "Attribute code" that you specified in "Manage Attributes" when you created your "vendor" attribute. For example, if you want to use the manufacturer attribute that already exists in Magento, the code is "manufacturer"

[image: screen]

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much @fschmengler. Sorry everyone if this was off topic. I am new here so learning the ropes and where best to ask the right questions! :)